# How to resolve “invalid number of 'breaks'”

Tags: r

I need help in resolving this error. I'm trying to create a histogram of the df_custdata file, and then extract a numeric column and put it in its own histogram.

Code:

```
df_custdata <- gsub(".", "", df_custdata)  
df_custdata <- as.numeric(df_custdata) 
hist(df_custdata)
```

Error:  Error in hist.default(f_custdata) : invalid number of 'breaks'

Comment: You are definitely missing some colons (`:`s).

Comment: Also a capital letter. `age` and `Age` are different variables in python, but clearly here should be the same. And indentation.

Answer (score 3):

In Python indentation is very important and so are colons.

For this you would also want to use a if statement and not a for loop.

This code works,

```
age = int(input("Enter You Age:"))

if age in range (14,18):
    print ("This student is in Highschool")
else:
    print ("This student is not in Highschool")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
age = int(input("Enter You Age:"))

if (age in range(14,18)):
    print ("This student is in Highschool")
else:
    print ("This student is not in Highschool")
```

Comment: I posted it to edit after, however, as I was editing the post, Sirsmorgasboard, just answered the same. No need to edit and post the full explanation

Answer (score -1):

The right syntax could be:

```
#"If ages = 14-18, then highschool, else not highschool"

age = int(input("Enter You Age:"))

if 14 <= age <= 18:
    print ("This student is in Highschool")

else:
    print ("This student is not in Highschool")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't work, still a syntax error.

Comment: I edited it. Please try this.